# White screen come at output after running cake php on wamp

Tags: cakephp, wamp

I have  project in cakephp, and I had made extensions needed to be done, but when I run project on wamp a white screen comes and if I echo something else in `webroot/index.php` that echo result is displayed, but when I run original file in `weroot/index.php` only white screen comes as output.

can any one tell me what can be the point that is missing by me.

Comment: did you clear the cache?

Comment: do you get any errors ?

Comment: no error, just white screen and trying to sort out this problem fro last week

Comment: @ShubhamSaini. check the error file in tmp/logs folder and see what is the error. Also try to print the error using error_reporting function.

Comment: i check in php error log and error is coming on app.php and error is self::_checkFatalError();

Comment: Paste the complete error text into your question. Use the [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/37130655/edit) link under your question

Comment: error displaying in error log:-

PHP Stack trace:
 PHP   1. {main}() C:\wamp\www\cake\app\webroot\index.php:0

 PHP   2. include() C:\wamp\www\cake\app\webroot\index.php:100

 PHP   3. Configure::bootstrap() C:\wamp\www\cake\lib\Cake\bootstrap.php:175

 PHP   4. include() C:\wamp\www\cake\lib\Cake\Core\Configure.php:92

[10-May-2016 09:56:36 Europe/Paris] PHP   5. App::shutdown() C:\wamp\www\cake\lib\Cake\Core\App.php:0

[10-May-2016 09:56:36 Europe/Paris] PHP   6. App::_checkFatalError() C:\wamp\www\cake\lib\Cake\Core\App.php:906

Comment: @ShubhamSaini You were asked to put that _in your question_, not as a comment where it's highly unreadable! Also a stacktrace usually comes with an error message, which you should include too.

Comment: so, how to sort this problem

Answer (score 0):

What's the value of Configure:read('debug') (it is set in config/core.php)? It should be greater than zero, so you'll get PHP errors displayed. Setting debug to zero is for live environments, in development mode you should use a value of 1, 2 or 3 (every level up means more debug information being shown).

For WAMP in the http-vhosts.conf file add something like

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

DocumentRoot "d:/websites/myapp/app/webroot/"
ServerName local.myapp

<Directory "d:/websites/myapp/app/webroot/">
    Options -Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride all
        Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Then in your windows hosts file i.e. 'C:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts' add

```
127.0.0.1    local.myapp
```

Restart Wamp then visiting local.myapp should give you a result.

ADDED-

Do you have display_errors set to 'on' in the php ini file? What does the php error log show you?

- Check that debug > 0
- Clear app/tmp/cache/persistent/*
- Check local vhost error log
- Check global httpd-error log
- Restart apache, (stop, start), restart cache services (memcached
  ect.)
- Enter the world of die(’stop’); from app/webroot/index.php and
  downward in your application